# Custom Query Pagination not working on static front page

Tags: wp-query, loop, pagination

I'm trying to add pagination to my site but it isn't working. 
Here's the code:

```
 <div id="gridcontainer" class="carousel">
    <?php
    $currentPage = get_query_var('page');
    $counter = 1; //start counter
    $grids = 2; //Grids per row

    global $query_string; //Need this to make pagination work

    $mosaicoMenu = new WP_Query(array(
                'post_type' => 'artist',
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'order' => ASC,
                'posts_per_page' => 8,
                'page' => $currentPage
            ));  

    if($mosaicoMenu->have_posts()) :  
        while($mosaicoMenu->have_posts()) :  
            $mosaicoMenu->the_post(); 

    //Show the left hand side column
    if($counter == 1) :
    ?>
        <div class="griditemleft">
            <div class="artista no-padding no-margin" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>), url('https://i.postimg.cc/9QS9Mn00/gradient2.png');">
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><span>+</span></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

    <?php
    //Show the right hand side column
    elseif($counter == $grids) :
    ?>
        <div class="griditemright">
            <div class="artista no-padding no-margin" style="background-image: url(<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>), url('https://i.postimg.cc/9QS9Mn00/gradient2.png');">
                <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?><span>+</span></a></p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    <?php
    $counter = 0;
    endif;

    $counter++;
    endwhile;

    echo paginate_links(array(
        'total' => $mosaicoMenu->max_num_pages
    ));
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    ?>
</div>
```

Everything looks fine but when I click on the pagination links it takes me to the same page.
I'm using this on a static front page, btw.

Answer (score 0):

It should be `paged` and not `page`

```
'paged' => $currentPage
```

Comment: Oh, thanks! This actually helped but now there's another problem. Once I go to the second page, I can't go back to the first. It's like they're both behaving as one page. Why would that be?

Comment: Since the `get_query_var('page')` takes values from the URL. 
You need to show us how the URL looks like when you back to the first page.

Comment: it's localhost/wordpress/page/2 (which makes sense, right?) but it won't even show the "previous page" link.

Comment: You should also change $current page line to  `$currentPage = get_query_var('paged',1);`

Comment: just tried that but i still have the same problem...